# OneDrive Api - With whom the item is shared?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

In OneDrive Business account I have shared files and folders and I'm trying to get a list of emails/users with whom the items are shared.

Both

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe
```

and

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
```

both produce a similar result. I get the list of files, but the property `Permissions` is never present. All I see is whether the items **are** shared, but not with **whom**.

Now, I'm aware of `/drive/items/{fileId}/permissions`, but this would mean checking the files one-by-one. My app deals with a lot of files and I would really appreciate a way to get hose permissions in bulk...

Is there such an option?

Comment: have you solved the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/sharedWithMe` is actually the opposite of what you're looking for. These are not files you've shared with others but rather files others have shared with *you*.

As for your specific scenario, `permissions` is unfortunately not supported in a collection. In other words, it isn't possible to `$epand=permissions` on the `/children` collection. Each file needs to be inspected separately.

You *can* however reduce the number of files you need to inspect by looking at the [shared](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/shared) property. For example, if the `scope` property is set to `user` you know this file was shared with a specific user. If the `shared` property is `null`, you know this file is only available to the current user.

You can also reduce the number of calls you're making by using [JSON Batching](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching). After constructing a list of shared files you want to check, you can use Batching to process them in blocks of 20. This should greatly reduce the amount of overhead and dramatically improve the overall performance.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, going to do it this way.

Comment: I'm really glad it helped but could you please mark the question as answered instead of adding a comment? This helps the next dev with your issue find the right answer a lot faster.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur  am also having the same issue. I got the shared by me files but still I didn't get the users  whom I share those file and the permissions . Is there any way to get that details using the Graph API ? any small suggestions will be a great help fro me at this stage

Answer (score 0):

`_api/web/onedriveshareditems?$top=100&$expand=SpItemUrl` might just do the trick. This is the URL that is used by the web interface of OneDrive. Hope it helps